# Emberjs How to update property on a component from route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi I would like to know what's the proper way to update a property on a component from the route?.

A little background on what I want to do:

I have two custom Buttons that I called CardButtons (based on material desing)  next to one blank area called description, what I want is to create a hover event that triggers an ajax call to retrive detailed data from a data base and render it on the description area.

**CHECK UPDATE**

So far I have created a route like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

selectedModule: '',

model: function () {

    return {
        selectedModule: 'employeeModule'
    };
},


actions: {

    showDescription: function (params) {

        this.set('model.selectedModule', params);

    }

}});
```

My route template call my component like this:

```
<div class="row">  
   {{sis-db-description-render idTitle=model.selectedModule}}
</div>
```

and the component is defined like this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

info: null,
ready: false,

didInsertElement: function () {

    this.queryData();


},

queryData: function (){
     /** Does an Ember.$.post request to the API  with the idTitle as param**/
}
});
```

the first time this executes it load perfectly the detail data but when I try to refresh the data the event does not trigger a second call. I bealive it is beacause I'm not updating the model in a proper way.

Any idea on how to update the component property?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @kumkanillam I was able to find a way on my route I added the next code:

```
 setupController: function (controller, model) {

    this._super(...arguments); //if its new/index.js route file then you can use controller argument this method.
    controller.set('selectedModule', 'employeeModule');
},


actions: {

    showDescription: function (params) {

        console.info(params);
        this.controllerFor('new.index').set('selectedModule', params);

    }

}
```

By doing so now the view updates the content every time, I still don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it works for  now.

Comment: `didInsertElement` will be called for initial render alone.

Comment: what method I need to use for updating? as far as I understand if I update the porperty on the route the component should rerender and call didUpdateAttrs method but this is not the case didUpdateAttrs is never called.

Comment: Actually you are not updating.In route `this.set('model.selectedModule', params);` here model is undefined. it's defined in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code, model is not defined in route. it's defined in corresponding controller through `setupController` hook.

```
showDescription: function (params) {
  this.set('model.selectedModule', params);
}
```

So in your case either you can define action in controller and update `model.selectedModule`
If you want to do it in route,

```
showDescription: function (params) {
      let cont = this.controllerFor('route-name');
      cont.set('model.selectedModule', params);
    }
```

Comment: Just one question all the guides I have read said that you must not use controllers, so this is making me crazy should I use them or not?

Comment: No propblem,you can very well use that.  https://github.com/emberjs/guides/pull/1762/files.. https://locks.svbtle.com/controllers-are-dead-long-life-controllers

Comment: ok so let me try this right now first I use ember g component new/index (my route is an index route) this should generate a controller and then??

Comment: You can play with this ember play ground https://ember-twiddle.com/ . I created [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4082f6a6a194fb8a2555526b1062ef42?openFiles=components.sis-db-description-render.js%2Ctemplates.components.sis-db-description-render.hbs) to demonstrate

Comment: thak you, but how to create the controller using ember-cli? if my route is new/index, according to the docs the name should be the same as your route and the given example is blog-post but in my case my route is a nested index route.

Comment: For component there is only one restriction, name should contain hyphen thats all. just `ember g component my-component` will do. `the name should be the same as your route` This is wrong for component, it denotes template `my-route.js===my-route.hbs`

Comment: sorry I mean controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133770/discussion-between-kumkanillam-and-deividkamui).